# What gcloud commands for translate must be executed per session?

Tags: authentication, gcloud

The codelab example for gcloud translate lists a number of commands under the [Authenticate API requests section](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-python3#3). Which of these are persistent and which must be executes per session?  I'd think once the key file is exported, that would be it.  But if I try to start a fresh session and just run the code in step 7 or 8, I get an "assertion error."

Answer (score 0):

Commands ran in [step 4](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-translation-python3#3) are not persistent except for the part where `key.json` is created. Yes you are correct that exporting the key file will authenticate your requests.

You got the "assertion error" because you did not export PROJECT_ID. You will also get an "authentication error" if you did not also export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

You just need to export PROJECT_ID and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS at least once when a new session is opened prior to running the code in step 7 or 8.

```
export PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value core/project)
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/key.json
```